# How to handle unused variable in parent class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns

Say suppose i am writing a library file which can be accessed by any one.

My design of the library goes like this.

```
Class College
{
    int no_of_staffs;
    string Name;
    int Area;
    string head;
        int rating ;
}

Class Department  : Class College
{
}

Class Classroom : Class Department
{
    string Leader;

}
```

While creating the instance for C, the memory will be allocated for Class A members too.

I am not going to use the all the member of A at all situations. But while creating the instance the memory will be allocated for them. But it seeems to be wasting the memory unnecessaily.

Is design wise anything goes wrong or is there is any way to handle this

Comment: Why is something needed in A but not in C? I have a feeling that you are misusing inheritance or that you could at least do better, but with the restricted example, it's impossible to tell. Can you give an example from which it is clear why something in the base is unused in derived classes?

Comment: This indicates a design flaw IMHO. Your question can't be answered from a general POV, with what you're giving in the example. May be you have a XY-problem. Whenever you're using inheritance you should seriously ask if `class C` **is a** `class B`, and `class B` **is a** `class A`, and these could be exchanged at the interface level arbitrarily (which is rarely the case).

Comment: @Vinoth, please see my answer's edit. I think you may need to reconsider your design.

Answer (score 4):

If I have an `Animal` class, it could have a `bool can_fly` field, because it applies to every class that inherits from it (`Lion`, `Monkey`, `Hawk`, etc...). If this isn't true of the member variables of `A` then your design is wrong.

I wouldn't put an `int max_flying_height` variable in `Animal`, because it wouldn't apply to `Monkey` or `Lion`. I *might* however have another class `Bird` that inherits from `Animal` and have an `int max_flying_height` member variable *there*.

**EDIT**

Looking at your edit, I think you are confused with when to use inheritance. Think of the "is a" vs. "has a" rule (if you have a "has a" relationship, then add a member variable. If you have an "is a" relationship, then add inheritance).

In my example, a `Lion` **is a** `Animal`, so it inherits. In your example, is a classroom a department? Or does a department have classrooms? Perhaps the department class should have an `std::vector` of classrooms?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to prevent a subclass from inheriting all the data members of its superclass. The idea behind object-oriented inheritance is that, if `C` inherits from `B`, then an instance of `C` *is also* an instance of `B`.

For example, say you have a function `myFunc(B b);`. Somewhere in the function, it accesses member `b.e`. Now, imaging that you have a `C` which inherits from `B` but doesn't contain member `int e`. If you try to pass it to `myFunc()`, you will succeed, because a `C` *is a* `B`, but then `myFunc()` would try to access the nonexistent member. This makes no sense.

There are also technical reasons, related to the layout of classes in memory, which make this not possible. When subclasses are laid out in memory, all members of the superclass come first, then all the members of the subclass. This means that a reference in memory to a `C` can be *the same reference* regardless of whether a function thinks such a refrence is a `B` or a `C`. If it's a `C`, the function knows about the whole variable; if it's a `B`, then it only knows up to when a `B` would normally end, and what comes later can be the rest of the object that makes it a `C`, or it can be random memory, or a different variable, or whatever.